# maven not picking the jars with build-version

Tags: java, maven-plugin, maven-3

Hi i am using the buildVersion plugin to add buildnumbers to my jar each time i take a build.  I am also building a **war** file which includes these jars.  While the jars are build in /target with buildVersion attached to their names, but inside the war file its not so .E.g if jar is myJar-1.0.2.jar where '2' is the buildVersion , inside the war file its still as myJar-1.0.jar..I think its so because in local repository the jar is stored as myJar-1.0.jar .. So it is possible that jars inside war file have the buildVersion attached ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the relevant pom snippet?  Your war project would need to refer to the dependant jars with the modified version.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumption are made in this response since no `pom.xml` file was given.

There is a difference between the name of the jar you find in your target folder and the jar that is installed in the repository.

The jar you find in the target folder will have the `<finalName>` while the jar installed in your repository will normally use the maven convention `${artifactId}-${version}`.

The jar included in your war is downloaded from the repository so will port the maven conventional name.

I always place the buildNumber in the MANIFEST file within the jar (together with other information) so it is available within the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have two jars attached to your build of the maven modules of the jar files and maven chooses the first available jar to include in the war assembly.